# Equivalent of "phrase"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

By *phrase* here I mean an expression consisting of multiple [separate] words, without being a full sentence.  (For example, *Witze reißen*, *mein sogenannter Urlaub*, *zwischen achtzig und scheintot*, etc.)

When I look for *phrase* in my English-German dictionaries, invariably the translation given is *Phrase*, but when I look up *Phrase* in my German dictionaries, the meaning given is something like *platitude* or *cliché* or *empty phrase*.

What would be a translation of *phrase* that more closely captures the sense I'm interested in?

The context for this is that I am making some lists of German vocabulary, and I want to classify the entries into words (Worte), phrases (???), and sentences (Sätze).  (I realize that this distinction is pretty artificial, especially in reference to a language with German's agglutinative tendencies; nevertheless, I find it helpful somehow.)

---

EDIT:

To clarify, I'm looking for a translation of *phrase* that only emphasizes the fragmentary nature of a phrase (i.e. it is not a full sentence), without implying anything about how colloquial, idiomatic, literary, etc., the phrase may be.  For example, *ein blaues Hemd* is a phrase.

---

EDIT 2:

OK, I found two potential translations:

[**Satzteil**](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Satzteil)

[**Teilsatz**](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Teilsatz)

Comment: _"Redewendung"_ might work in your context.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Maybe I'm being too literal here, but I thought that *Redewendung* was the same thing as *turn of phrase*, in which case it would be a bit more specific than what I'm looking for.  The distinction I'm making is admittedly subtle (if not downright questionable), but, as I understand it, all the expressions that I'd classify as "turns of phrase" I would also classify as "phrases", but the converse is not true.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: ...For example, I'd classify the expression "to draw a distinction" as a phrase, but not as a turn of phrase.  In contrast, "to draw a line in the sand" is a turn of phrase in my book.  (And so is "in my book," for that matter.)  The only difference between the two is that a turn of phrase is somewhat less prosaic, more flamboyant than a mere phrase.

Comment: No _"turn of a phrase"_ doesn't make sense. I think _"Redewendung"_ is the correct translation (see [here](https://translate.google.de/#de/en/Redewendung) also)

Comment: Some concise examples would be nice also.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I gave three at the beginning of my original post, but I just added one more.

Comment: _"mein sogennanter Urlaub"_ won't fall in the _phrase_ category, at least not as far I understood your context.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: why not?  It fits the description I gave: it's an expression, made up of multiple separate words, and it's not a full sentence.

Comment: But _sogenaannt_ is an arbitrary adjective. So _"mein schöner Urlaub"_, _"mein verregneter Urlaub"_, _"mein teurer Urlaub"_, etc. would also fall in that category. Do you want to list all possible combinations of _Urlaub_ with matching adjectives?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes, you have that right, *sogennant* is an arbitrary adjective, just as *blau* is.  The fact that I'm giving a particular title to my list does not mean that I intend to list *all* possibilities.  (I also have a list called *Worte*, and there's no implication that it lists "all possible" words.)  I don't know where you get your objection from.  You're reading a lot more into my post than what I wrote.

Comment: Well, your list could be titled _"Beliebige Wortkombinationen"_ then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Phrase" has two meanings in German, firstly the one you mentioned, secondly, in lingusitic terminology, the one you are looking for (basically the same as in English). 
Satzteil or Teilsatz could work too, but strictly speaking these are grammatical expressions for specific parts of a sentence (= clauses) and not just phrases.

Depending on your readership, I'd probably use either "Phrase" or "Ausdruck" (=expression).

"Versatzstück", as sb. mentioned above, doesn't work at all in this context. "Redewendung" might be OK for some entries, but it's more like an idiom or saying, so if you have a vocab entry like "ein kleines Haus" this could be a phrase (in the lingusitic sense) or an "Ausdruck", but not a "Redewendung".

Answer (score 2):

A concatenation of some words, ready to be used in a sentence, can be called

> [Versatzstück](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Versatzst%C3%BCck) (*plural:* Versatzstücke)

which can also be a complete sentence or even more.

Another option is

> [Textbaustein](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Textbaustein) (*plural:* Textbausteine)

Answer (score 2):

> I am making some lists of German vocabulary, and I want to classify the entries into words (Worte), phrases (???), and sentences (Sätze).

**Wortgruppe** would fit in this context.
[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wortgruppe) defines it as:

> Gruppe von Wörtern, die zusammengehören